# My Mojang service ping script isn't working

Tags: php, minecraft

I'm trying to make a way in PHP to ping Mojang services and then output the result into a text file for a project I'm working on.

I borrowed parts of the code all around the internet, and have created this:

```
<?php
    //Puts the received JSON from status.mojang.com to a variable;
    $json = file_get_contents("http://status.mojang.com/check");

    //If the JSON is NOT empty, then decode it;
    if(!empty($json)) {
    $result = json_decode($json,true);
    }

    //Array to store all 8 JSON mojang status web services;
    $server = array("minecraft.net", "login.minecraft.net", "session.minecraft.net", "account.mojang.com", "auth.mojang.com", "skins.minecraft.net", "authserver.mojang.com", "sessionserver.mojang.com");

    //We gotta add into $result[0] a number for each server([0] for the first, [1] for the second, etc.);
    $i = 0;

    //For each server from the array, draw a DIV, which the background-color corresponds the status(Green:Online, Yellow:Semi-Online, Red:Offline);
    foreach ($server as $address) {
            if (isset($result[$i][$address]) && $result[$i][$address]=="green") {
                    //Echoes the ONLINE status;
                    echo "<div style='background-color: lightgreen;'>" . $address . "</div>";
            }elseif($result[$i][$address]=="yellow"){
                    //Echoes the SEMI-ONLINE status;
                    echo "<div style='background-color: yellow;'>" . $address . "</div>";
            }else{
                    //Echoes the OFFLINE status;
                    echo "<div style='background-color: red;'>" . $address . "</div>";
            }
            //Increment 1 to $i, so then, you can draw the status for the second server, and so on;
            $i++;
    }
?>
```

Now, when testing it it shows "minecraft.net" as online but when checking the place where I get the JSON from (http://status.mojang.com/check) it shows all of the services as online.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running your code, it's filled with notices:

> Notice: Undefined index: login.minecraft.net
>
> Notice: Undefined index: session.minecraft.net
>
> Notice: Undefined index: account.mojang.com

et cetera.

The problem is that JSON are unordered, but you're attempting to read them in the order you declared them:

```
'minecraft.net'
'login.minecraft.net'
'session.minecraft.net'
'account.mojang.com'
'auth.mojang.com'
'skins.minecraft.net'
'authserver.mojang.com'
'sessionserver.mojang.com'
```

But they show up in this order when turned back into an array from the results:

```
'minecraft.net'
'session.minecraft.net'
'account.mojang.com'
'auth.mojang.com'
'skins.minecraft.net'
'authserver.mojang.com'
'sessionserver.mojang.com'
'api.mojang.com'
'textures.minecraft.net'
```

You need to make your `foreach` generic by using whatever server comes first like so:

```
<?php

//Puts the received JSON from status.mojang.com to a variable;
$json = file_get_contents("http://status.mojang.com/check");

//If the JSON is NOT empty, then decode it;
if(!empty($json))
{
    $result = json_decode($json, true);
}

//For each result given to us, draw a DIV, which the background-color corresponds the status(Green:Online, Yellow:Semi-Online, Red:Offline);
foreach($result as $address)
{
    $server = array_keys($address)[0];
    $colour = array_values($address)[0];
    switch($colour)
    {
        case 'green':  $colour = 'lightgreen'; break;
        case 'red':    break; //Do nothing, red is good
        case 'yellow': break; //Do nothing, yellow is good
        default:       $colour = 'red'; break; //Something went wrong, assume it's down
    }
    echo "<div style=\"background-color: $colour;\">$server</div>" . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Which produces the following HTML:

```
<div style="background-color: lightgreen;">minecraft.net</div>
<div style="background-color: lightgreen;">session.minecraft.net</div>
<div style="background-color: lightgreen;">account.mojang.com</div>
<div style="background-color: lightgreen;">auth.mojang.com</div>
<div style="background-color: lightgreen;">skins.minecraft.net</div>
<div style="background-color: lightgreen;">authserver.mojang.com</div>
<div style="background-color: lightgreen;">sessionserver.mojang.com</div>
<div style="background-color: lightgreen;">api.mojang.com</div>
<div style="background-color: lightgreen;">textures.minecraft.net</div>
```